# transform:scale() makes elements on bottom right to disappear

Tags: javascript, css, angular, css-transforms

THIS HAPPENS ONLY ON GOOGLE CHROME, WINDOWS 10

I am working on a flipbook that checks user's screen size and using transform:scale() shows content as big as possible. Then there is a zoom button that increases/decreases the scale factor. I am catching the mouse down and move events and allowing the user to scroll by dragging with the mouse. The app is built with the help of Angular. The problem I face is that when user zooms quite a lot, the contents at the right-bottom disappear. Here is a live link http://bg.e-prosveta.bg/fulldemo/4iyEkxtEbY-946/40?page=11. The page structure is as:

```
<div class="outer-pages-wrapper" [ngStyle]="{'max-width': (containerWidth - 100) + 'px', width: ((ebook.width * ebook.scaleFactor) + (hideRight ? 0 : (ebook.width * ebook.scaleFactor))) + 'px', height: (ebook.height * ebook.wrapperScaleFactor) + 'px'}">
  <div class="inner-pages-wrapper" [ngStyle]="{transform:'scale(' + ebook.scaleFactor + ')', '-ms-transform':'scale(' + ebook.scaleFactor + ')','-webkit-transform':'scale(' + ebook.scaleFactor + ')'}">
    <app-ebook-page></app-ebook-page>
    <app-ebook-page></app-ebook-page>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some relevent CSS rules:

```
.outer-pages-wrapper {
  display:flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner-pages-wrapper {
  transform-origin: left top;
  -ms-transform-origin: left top;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  display:flex;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what happens after zooming 5-6 times on Chrome for Windows:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. I tried the link you posted and nothing is disappearing?

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis please, start zooming and moving the page to the bottom right.

Comment: Browser zoom or the zoom button?

Comment: The zoom button

Comment: Sorry but I clicked your zoom button like 100 times and it seems to work fine. Tried in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis The transformation-origin is set to `left top`, but if you move with mouse drag to the bottom right of the page, you will see that elements start to disappear.

Comment: I cannot reproduce either, i am using chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.w2.h2 {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't on my end. I am using Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10. Have you changed something else as well?

Comment: You're either looking at a cached version or you haven't applied the style correctly. Can you provide a link to a new build, which includes these styles? If I open your provided link and apply the above styles via `inspector-stylesheet` it [works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd7f9.jpg). Note that in the above screenshot the contents where hidden before i applied the fix and showed up after I did.

Comment: It might be the case that `h2` and `w2` classes are produced at build time by some minification plugin (therefore end up having different names at each build), in which case you need to target the appropriate elements in your markup. It's [these two elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYgs2.png) which both need `overflow: visible`.

Comment: I started to wonder why these rules are needed. Both elements have fixed height so the hidden divs are not outside their parents.

Answer (score 3):

There is a limit for zooming in browser, If you zoom beyond the limit, things will not look good.
My suggestion is limit the zoom upto some point and then disable the zoom button if it reaches the limit.

For fixing the issue - you can set the overflow to the common class of elements.

```
#ebook-40 .ws0 {
  overflow: auto; 
}
```

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

WITH OUT overflow -

[image]

With Overflow -
[image]

Comment: Sorry but your suggestion doesn't work. Please see the updated question. I put a screenshot with your rule being applied to the element but it still disappears.

Comment: It works fine for me with the fix. Can you try adding css to class .pf or id #pfb. check updated answer

Comment: but are you saying if you don't put the `overflow` rule, the elements disappear and if you put it, then they don't disappear?

Comment: yeah, if overflow not there - then they are disappearing, if you put it , then they are appearing when yo do 5X zoom

Comment: Can you try with Chrome? It doesn't work on my side

Comment: Yeah tried in chrome, its working for me. check the screenshots

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204202/discussion-between-allabakash-and-martin-dimitrov).

Comment: Sorry I will be back in 2 hours. I will then look again and will let you know. Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, I had a similar problem and I added

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
```

to the disappearing element... An old hack that still seems to work!